# Core data - double attribute - basic mathematical operations

Tags: objective-c, math, core-data, double, nsnumber

I have in CoreData a entity. It has a attribute "score". The score has type double, but when I want to work with the number, xcode shows, that is a NSNumber, not double. So, I can't use basic mathematical operations. I need increment,decrement,devide etc. How can I do it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can read out the stored value with `-doubleValue` (`NSNumber`).
2. You can select *Decimal* instead of *Double*- IIRC you will get instance objects of `NSDecimalNumber`.

BTW: Using double for a score will lead to surprising behavior. You shouldn't do that either way. Decimals or integers treated as fixed-point would be the better choice.